# Integrate Whatsapp business API with Flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, whatsapp

I want to integrate Whatsapp for business API with a Flutter application.
Where do i start and is this possible ?
Thank you.

Comment: use something like twillio or messagebird

Comment: Is it possible to use Whatsapp for business API by itself without using twilio ?

Comment: yes but do you have a approved account.it's not a easy process. Facebook encourage to go through a solution provider.this is from there site "To go to market on WhatsApp Business API during this time, please consider using a Business Solution Provider. Facebook has partnered with over 46 global providers who specialize in WhatsApp business to consumer messaging. Search the WA Business API provider directory now."https://www.facebook.com/business/m/whatsapp/business-api

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flutter_share_me` plugin from Dart and implement some plugin setting from Android manifest and need to update Kotlin to the latest version then it's working fine to open Whatsapp Business APP.

Here are some code snippets to help you:

Use Share.whatsapp_business Switch Case

```
Future<void> onButtonTap(Share share, CustomerDetails customerDetails) async {
    String msg = "Thank you for contacting us! We will be in touch shortly";
    //"Customer Name : "+customerDetails.customerName.toString()+"\n"+"Address : "+customerDetails.address+"\n"+"Mobile No. : " + customerDetails.contactNo1.toString();
   String url = 'https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share_me';

String response;
final FlutterShareMe flutterShareMe = FlutterShareMe();
switch (share) {
  case Share.facebook:
    response = await flutterShareMe.shareToFacebook(url: url, msg: msg);
    break;
  case Share.twitter:
    response = await flutterShareMe.shareToTwitter(url: url, msg: msg);
    break;

  case Share.whatsapp_business:
    response = await flutterShareMe.shareToWhatsApp4Biz(msg: msg);
    break;
  case Share.share_system:
    response = await flutterShareMe.shareToSystem(msg: msg);
    break;
  case Share.whatsapp_personal:
    response = await flutterShareMe.shareWhatsAppPersonalMessage(
        message: msg, phoneNumber: '+91'+customerDetails.contactNo1);
    break;
  case Share.share_telegram:
    response = await flutterShareMe.shareToTelegram(msg: msg);
    break;
}
debugPrint(response);
}
```